# TCategoryPanelGroup not repainting Panels on collapse when using styles

Tags: themes, vcl, vcl-styles, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I'm using the style "Charcoal Dark Slate" right out of the box and having issues with the `TCategoryPanelGroup` not refreshing its category panels.

In this setup all category panels all expanded.
Each panel has ONE control, a `TFrame` with a few child controls. The `TFrame` has its `Align` property set to `alClient`.

[image]

If I collapse the middle one, every following panel isn't redrawing all controls. I have to move the mouse over them to get them redrawn. If I collapse the first panel, panel 2 and 3 aren't redrawn etc... (basically all panels that moved up)

[image]

I have tried to `Invalidate()`, `Repaint()` and `Refresh()` the `TCategoryPanelGroup` on the collapse event `OnCollapse`. I have also tried to `Invalidate()`, `Repaint()` and `Refresh()` the panel itself in desperation. Nothing helps.

I noticed that all panels are repainted on resize. My workaround now is to have the `OnCollapse` and `OnExpand` event handlers to quickly resize the `TCategoryPanelGroup` control.

```
void __fastcall TGraph_Form::CategoryPanelCollapse(TObject *Sender) {

    TCategoryPanel      *p = reinterpret_cast<TCategoryPanel*>(Sender);
    TCategoryPanelGroup *g = reinterpret_cast<TCategoryPanelGroup*>(p->PanelGroup);

    // Fix style bug on collapse events
    // Force a resize to redraw all panels
    g->Width++;
    g->Width--;
}
```

Adjusting the `Height` property of the `TCategoryPanelGroup` will not force all panels to redraw, it has to be the `Width` property.

Have I missed something here or is this indeed another VCL style bug?

Comment: My workaround is to set panels  visible=false, application.procesmessages then visible=true using a timer with 200 ms interval  on OnExpand. No other way found.